# Pyqt add 9 elements in layout and then lot of layout in group box

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make elements in row in one layout and a lot of layouts will be in GroupBox, it must  be like this.

[Result Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY9fS.jpg)

I try to release this

```
formLayout = QFormLayout()

for i in range(50):
    formLayout.addRow(QLabel(i), QPushButton("Start"))

groupBox.setLayout(formLayout)
self.scrollArea.setWidget(groupBox)
self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
```

[Result from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yir1U.jpg)

I know that i should make in grib layout, because i have a lot of elements, but how can I create a layout with layouts which everyone have 9 elements?

Just explain how it should be grouped , like this `scrollArea->groupBox->formLayout.addrow(elements)`
I don't need full code, him I can write myself.

Comment: The layout you're showing is not a form layout, it *could* be a grid layout, but it actually seems more like a QTableView (or QTableWidget) or even a QTreeView (if those small arrows on the left are used to *expand* elements). Using nested layouts in this case might not be a good solution, as each layout would be independent from the others, with the result that the widgets might not be properly aligned.

Comment: Understand, this small arrows for expand element. So the best way will be QTreeView?

Comment: Yes, in that case a QTreeView with a QStandardItemModel or a QTreeWidget might help, then use [`setItemWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget) to add  buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout you're showing is not a form layout, it could be a grid layout, but it actually seems more like a QTableView (or QTableWidget) or even a QTreeView (if those small arrows on the left are used to expand elements). Using nested layouts in this case might not be a good solution, as each layout would be independent from the others, with the result that the widgets might not be properly aligned. This small arrows for expand element in that case a QTreeView with a QStandardItemModel or a QTreeWidget might help, then use setItemWidget() to add buttons. –
[musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).